# Использование в объекте data множественный ключ

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vue.js

Как можно использовать в объекте `data` множественный ключ? Скажем нужны два символа в `'views.Cards.State.b'`: `x` или `l`:

```javascript
data: () => ({          
  states: [
    {caption: 'views.Cards.State.a', code: 'a', color: 'accent'},
    {caption: 'views.Cards.State.b', code: 'x|l', color: 'error'}
  ]
})
```

Comment: Во первых не ключа, а свойства обьекта судя по Вашему коду, а во вторых если вам надо множественное значение положите туда массив.

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужна коллекция для хранения не одного значение, используйте массив

```
data: () => ({          
  states: [
    {caption: 'views.Cards.State.a', code: 'a', color: 'accent'},
    {caption: 'views.Cards.State.b', code: ['x', l], color: 'error'}
  ]
})
```

Comment: выдает ошибку 
Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.

Comment: Не должно быть там ошибки, значит что то не так делаете

Comment: Скорее всего это значение где-то потом в другом месте используется в качестве ключа